# SQL conditional JOIN - JOIN point defined based on joined_table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

**Scenario:**
In each of the below, "created date", "other_created_date" and "date" are a Day (i.e. 2012-01-03)

**Table 1:**
fields:
ID  |  created_date

**Table 2:**
fields:
ID  | table_1_fk | other_created_date

**Table 3:**
fields:
date

---

**The Goal:**

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_fk
FULL OUTER JOIN table_3
ON table_3.date = ( 
    CASE 
        WHEN table_1.created_date > table_2.other_created_date THEN table_1.created_date
        ELSE table_2.other_created_date
        END
)
```

Basically, I'm interested in (Table_1 + Table_2) JOINed on Table_3, where if the first statement is true we join on Table_1's date, and if the second statement is true we join on Table_2's date

Is this possible or is there a better way to go at this?

Comment: I would rather join table3 twice in a fixed way and would pick the right value in the select list using conditional expression.

Comment: @Shadow could you provide a query sample that would do that? Right now I have this broken up into two separate queries and I then just add the two sets in a different language, but I'm trying to get this all into SQL

Comment: can you clean up the tags on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_fk
FULL OUTER JOIN table_3
ON table_3.date = GREATEST(table_1.created_date,table_2.other_created_date)
```

Comment: I wish I could easily convey a better sense of how much time and effort this just saved me... I've been at this question for the better part of a few days. thank you, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I like Bernd's answer.  However, without knowing anything about the content of these tables, I think it's worth your while to evaluate the performance difference between doing what you are suggesting and simply having two separate outer joins.  I know I've done creative things in the joins before, and the database will manage it, but HOW it manages it may not be what I had in mind at all, especially if dealing with tens of millions of records.

As an example, this is what the SQL might look like if you used two outer joins instead of trying to merge them into one.  It will potentially be a lot more code, which is why you will need to benchmark it to see if it matters.

I know I used left joins here -- I'm always a little suspicious when I see a full outer, but that's not to say it wasn't exactly what you wanted.  But this is for illustration purposes only:

```
SELECT
  case
    when table_1.created_date > table_2.other_created_date then
      t3a.<field_1>
    else
      t3b.<field_1>
  end
FROM
  table_1
  JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_fk
  left join table3 t3a on
    table3.date = table_1.created_date
  left join table3 t3b on
    table3.date = table_2.other_created_date
```

-- EDIT --

Here's an example of where a compactly-coded join condition had horrible performance and a workaround that was way more code but worth it:

[PostgreSQL Joining Between Two Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030589/postgresql-joining-between-two-values/33282939#33282939)

Comment: Thanks @Hambone I'll be coming back to this syntax to benchmark it against Bernd's solution moving forward - I appreciate the thought in spelling out a second way of solving the problem.

Comment: regarding the FULL OUTER - the reason I opted for that is that my `table_3` is actually just a generated series of dates (days), and the FULL OUTER makes sure that rows with a 0 count are still included... although there's likely a better way to achieve that as well

Comment: That does make sense -- thanks.  Have you considered generate_series() instead of your table3?

Comment: yes, that's actually what table3 is, is a `generate_series()`, but I just called it `table3` here to keep the question simple and easy to explain