# PostgreSQL - Filter column 2 results based on column 1

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Forgive a novice question. I am new to postgresql.

I have a database full of transactional information. My goal is to iterate through each day since the first transaction, and show how many unique users made a purchase on that day, or in the 30 days previous to that day.

So the # of unique users on 02/01/2016 should show all unique users from 01/01/2016 through 02/01/2016. The # of unique users on 02/02/2016 should show all unique users from 01/02/2016 through 02/02/2016.

Here is a fiddle with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3d90/1

The result should be something like this:

```
December 17 2014 -- 1
December 18 2014 -- 2
December 19 2014 -- 3
...
January 13 2015 -- 16
January 19 2015 -- 15
January 20 2015 -- 15
...
```

The best I've come up with is the following:

```
SELECT
to_char(S.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS my_day,
COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE
      WHEN S.created > S.created - INTERVAL '30 days'
      THEN S.user_id
      END)
FROM
    transactions S
GROUP BY my_day
ORDER BY my_day;
```

As you can see, I have no idea how I could reference what exists in column one in order to specify what date range should be included in the filter.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the schema and some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: @MarekSkiba Just added it. Take a crack at it, if you can! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you do a self-join, it would give you the results you seek:

```
select
  t1.created,
  count (distinct t2.user_id)
from
  transactions t1
  join transactions t2 on
    t2.created between t1.created - interval '30 days' and t1.created
group by
  t1.created
order by
  t1.created
```

That said, I think this is going to do form of a cartesian join in the background, so for large datasets I doubt it's very efficient.  If you run into huge performance problems, there are ways to make this a lot faster...  but before you address that, find out if you need to.

-- EDIT 8/20/16 --

In response to your issue with the performance of this...  yes, it's a pig.  I admit it.  I encountered a similar issue here:

[PostgreSQL Joining Between Two Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030589/postgresql-joining-between-two-values)

The same concept for your example is this:

```
with xtrans as (
  select created, created + generate_series(0, 30) as create_range, user_id
  from transactions
)
select
  t1.created,
  count (distinct t2.user_id)
from
  transactions t1
  join xtrans t2 on
    t2.create_range = t1.created
group by
  t1.created
order by
  t1.created
```

It's not as easy to follow, but it should yield identical results, only it will be significantly faster because it's not doing the "glorified cross join."

Comment: Thanks a ton! It gives the results I'm looking for. Definitely puts me on the right track. Unfortunately, I am working with a very large dataset, so this is very slow (>10 minutes for a LIMIT 10 query). Any thoughts on optimizing?